# Why does HttpURLConnection fail on android but succeed in java Eclipse?

Tags: java, android

I don't know why HttpURLConnection fails on android but succeeds in java Eclipse. I have been facing that problem for many days and trying to solve it but have never pass it. The code in my case as followings:

```
try {  
        url = "https://mobitrade.vpbs.com.vn:8080/getlistckindex/hnx";
        URL urlGetSymbol = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlGetSymbol.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        String responseString = response.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
                .replaceAll("\"", "");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code works fine in java eclipse but don't work on android due to con.connect() gets error.

Comment: what's the error

Comment: @RishiSaraf the error is that connection fails. It leads to responseString to be null.

Comment: have you supplied appropriate permissions?

Comment: @KaranMer I did that in AndroidManifest.xml. For instance, I always use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using different api packages for HttpURLConnection so please check that. you can use java.net.HttpURLConnection api for the same.

Comment: I use java.net.HttpURLConnection api. Also, I have just tried with jsoup and okHttp, but it has not worked on android. It is strange because I have successfully done with java eclipse but failed in android. Did you try to run the code in android?

Comment: can you use HttpsURLConnection class for the https url.

Comment: Please remove 's' from https url because if you are using https so you have to integrate https ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to your Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: @hyjoon I alsways do that when writting android apps.